# Is it possible to use ternary operators in a for loop in PHP?

Tags: php, html, loops

I am creating a simple one-page web page and wish to use a for loop to output the navigation links. I am having an issue in pairing the stage number (`$x`) to a string.

The final output is expected to be/should be:

- Stage 1, Victoria Bridge, Leeds
- Stage 2, Second Stage Location
- Stage 3, Third Stage Location
- Stage 4, Any Other
- Stage 5, Any Other

However, the output is

- Stage 1, Third Stage Location
- Stage 2, Third Stage Location
- Stage 3, Third Stage Location
- Stage 4, Any Other
- Stage 5, Any Other

And I am not too sure where I have gone wrong.

I have tried using if/else statements as shown below.

```php
<!-- vertical nav -->
      <nav class="v-nav p-4">
        <p class="title">Stage</p>
        <ul>
          <?php

          for ($x = 1; $x <= 21; $x++) {

            if ($x = 1) {
              $place = 'Victoria Bridge, Leeds';
            } else if ($x = 2) {
              $place = 'Victoria Bridge 2, Leeds';
            } else {
              $place = 'test'
            }

          ?>
            <li>
              <a href="#stage<?php echo $x ?>" data-number="<?php echo $x ?>">
                <span class="label">Stage <?php echo $x ?> - <?php echo $place ?></span>
                <span class="dot"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

It caused `$x` to repeat past 21 times for some reason and prevent the load of all the other page elements. Below is what I currently have using ternary operators and can't seem to figure out where the flaw is.

```php
<!-- vertical nav -->
      <nav class="v-nav p-4">
        <p class="title">Stage</p>
        <ul>
          <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 21; $x++) { ?>
            <li>
              <a href="#stage<?php echo $x ?>" data-number="<?php echo $x ?>">
                <span class="label">
                  <?php
                    $navLink = 'Stage '.$x.', '.(
                      $x == 1 ? 'Victoria Bridge, Leeds' :
                      $x == 2 ? 'Second Stage Location' :
                      $x == 3 ? 'Third Stage Location' : 'Any Other');
                    echo $navLink;
                  ?>
                </span>
                <span class="dot"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Kind Regards

Comment: In your first set of code `if ($x = 1)` is assigning 1 and not testing equal to 1.

Comment: Also, for nested ternary operators you really need brackets.

Comment: Better still, use a  `switch` rather than multiple conditions.

Comment: Or put your stages in an array using the stage as the key and the text as the value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the operator in your if,

You are using **=** instead of **==**

**Use this instead :**

```
<!-- vertical nav -->
      <nav class="v-nav p-4">
        <p class="title">Stage</p>
        <ul>
          <?php

          for ($x = 1; $x <= 21; $x++) {

            if ($x == 1) {
              $place = 'Victoria Bridge, Leeds';
            } else if ($x == 2) {
              $place = 'Victoria Bridge 2, Leeds';
            } else {
              $place = 'test'
            }

          ?>
            <li>
              <a href="#stage<?php echo $x ?>" data-number="<?php echo $x ?>">
                <span class="label">Stage <?php echo $x ?> - <?php echo $place ?></span>
                <span class="dot"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

**For first one** operator comparison was wrong use `==` instead of `=`

```
if ($x == 1) {
          $place = 'Victoria Bridge, Leeds';
        } else if ($x == 2) {
          $place = 'Victoria Bridge 2, Leeds';
        } else {
          $place = 'test'
        }
```

And For Ternary operator use correct brackets open and close respectively

**[Sanbox link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4d24d920c7901e95dd34b8eae3afc21c6c4dfe1)**

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 21; $x++) {
            $place  = ($x == 1 ?'Victoria Bridge, Leeds' :
               ($x == 2 ? 'Second Stage Location' :
                ($x == 3 ? 'Third Stage Location' : 'Any Other')
               )
            );
         echo $place.'<br>';
     }
```